# Terrible lag in HTML5/JavaScript game when animating

Tags: javascript, css, html, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

My HTML5/JavaScript game (for the windows store) is lagging constantly! I have used barely any resources and I have used gsap for animating the bullets and mines. For example: `http://203.81.207.90/default.html` in Chrome enabling everything under rendering shows the lag immediately (the background and mines lag the most).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the tiny interval (10ms) used in most `setInterval()`'s.
increasing the interval should help and since javascript is a single threaded language, using lots of timers basically queue's them (performance issue) try using less timers by putting multiple functions in single timers

Answer (score 0):

That's not lag. It's the browser trying to scroll when you press the right arrow key. Put e.preventDefault() at the start of your keydown handler.

Comment: The OP isn't talking about the scrolling issue, as he said his app is for the windows store. the mines sort of skip frames randomly